# Verify the part of text using protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I want to verify that whether certain text exists in a string or not (using protractor).

In my case, the following code:

```
element(by.css('h1.text-center')).getText();
```

will result to:

```
ArrowGrey Slim Fit Formal Trouser -1 (Size - X)
```

Now, I want to verify that whether the string `ArrowGrey Slim Fit Formal Trouser` is contained in the above text or not.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 14):

There are multiple ways to have a partial string match using `jasmine`:

```
expect(text).toContain("ArrowGrey Slim Fit Formal Trouser");
expect(text).toMatch("ArrowGrey Slim Fit Formal Trouser");
expect(text).toStartWith("ArrowGrey Slim Fit Formal Trouser");
```

where [`toStartWith()` is coming from `jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers#tostartwith).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @winlinuz for your help.
I myself found the solution to it. Using **toContain** would work.

```
expect(element(by.css('h1.text-center')).getText()).toContain('ArrowGrey Slim Fit Formal Trouser');
```

Above code works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can assert this way:

```
expect(element(by.css('h1.text-center')).getText()).toEqual('ArrowGrey Slim Fit Formal Trouser');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but actually I want to verify whether the second string would be contained in the first string or not. The above code is resulting into assertion failure :(
Please help!